# Fast way to determine filtered values in a Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I need to check if a host of pivot tables are correctly filtering out the right items. Right now I am scrolling down and eye-balling to see if certain entries are excluded and nothing else. But each of my fields have 10,000+ items and it's taking forever and I am worried that I might miss something. Is there some way that I can get excel to simply list the values excluded in a Pivot table?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's one non-VBA solution:** Make two new copies of your PivotTable. Remove every field except the Field of interest. If it's NOT already a Row field, then drag it to the rows pane. Clear the filter on one of them. Do a VLOOKUP or simple MATCH on the unfiltered one against the filtered one. Whatever items throw errors are the ones that have been filtered out.

[image]

You then simply have to filter your lookup column to show just the errors, and on the PivotTable on the right you have your list of things that have been filtered out:

[image]

**Here's a VBA approach:**

You can find a very efficient Invert Filter routine at the bottom of my post http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/12/03/inversely-filter-a-pivot-based-on-an-external-range/ that can be used to simply invert the PivotField filter selections so that you can see what was hidden before. So all you need to do is copy the PivotTable of interest, select a cell in the field of interest, and run the PivotFilter_Invert routine.

**And here's a sneak peak of a commercial Add-In that will do it for you:**

[image]

Note the 'Show all', 'Show filtered' and 'Show unfiltered' options at the bottom. In the screenshot above, it's in 'Show all' mode. Here's what you get if you click 'Show filtered' and 'Show unfiltered'
[image]   [image]

After thinking about your question/requirements, I'm going to add an option 'Copy list to worksheet' or similar so you can dump a report of what is shown and what is not to the worksheet.

It also lets you execute multiple wildcard filters and then filter the PivotTable on the resulting subset:
[image]

I'll be posting about this further over at www.DailyDoseOfExcel.com in the coming month if you're interested in looking at it further.

Comment: Thanks for your response @jeffreyweir. I dont know who downvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A few years later, but: In VBA, the `PivotField` object has members `.HiddenItems` and `.VisibleItems` in addition to the basic `.PivotItems`.  Looping through `.PivotItems` and checking for `.visible = True` is slow, but simply converting `.HiddenItems` or `.VisibleItems` into an array is fast.

Here is a sample function for hidden items.  If you replace "hidden" with "visible" throughout this function, it will give the visible items.

```
Function PivotFieldHiddenItems(myField As PivotField) As Variant
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim hiddenItems As PivotItems
    Dim returnArray() As Variant
    
    Set hiddenItems = myField.HiddenItems

    If hiddenItems.Count = 0 Then
        'If no hidden items, return empty array
        PivotFieldHiddenItems = Array()
    Else
        'Send the hidden items to a 1 dimensional array
        ReDim returnArray(hiddenItems.Count - 1)
        For i = 0 To hiddenItems.Count - 1
            returnArray(i) = hiddenItems(i + 1)
        Next
        PivotFieldHiddenItems = returnArray
    End If

    'To demo, show results in message box
    MsgBox Join(PivotFieldHiddenItems, "," & vbLf), , "Hidden Fields: " &     
    myField.Name

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the original data table, I believe the simplest method would be to add an additional column to the right, which will hold a value indicating presence in the pivot table. Something like [assuming the unique ID is in A1, and the pivot table is in column A of sheet2], this cell would be in eg e1, and copied down]:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(A1,'Sheet2'!A:A,0))
```

This will now show TRUE where there was no match found on the pivot table, and FALSE otherwise.

Now you could have an additional pivot table which picks up the expanded original data set, filtered to show only items which have TRUE in the new field.

Comment: It is far more efficient to perform the lookup against an unfiltered PivotTable than the DataTable, because the PivotField contains only unique items, but the DataTable contains duplicates and could be orders of magnitude longer. So most of the computationally expensive resulting MATCH formulas would be redundant. 

Furthermore, there is a big different between what is 'Filtered' in a PivotTable and what isn't visible because a filter has been applied at another level. This approach doesn't account for that. My approach does.

Comment: @jeffreyweir I suppose it's a matter of preference as to whether you want to check an actual 'filter' [your method], or to check all values which have been hidden through any means [whether filtering, nil values, etc.]. Also, I am not filtering *against* the data table, I am simply containing the calculations there. So while there may be may more iterations of the formula, the formula itself still references the filtered pivot table. Finally, a mention of '10k+' implies to me that computational power is not particularly relevant in this case.

Comment: On your first point, it's not so much a matter of 'preference' as a different requirement.

Comment: @ Grade 'Eh' Bacon On the efficiency front, computational power is *very* relevent. The pivot has *at least* 10,000 items in it. I suspect the OP mentioned the 10k+ figure not so much because there are just over 10k items in it, but rather because a PivotFilter won't show more than 10k items, meaning they can't eyeball the filter itself. Given Pivots are used to aggregate things, that data *might* have just 10k rows, but equally it might have 20k,  100k or 1000k rows. Your approach requires MAX(X,11000) lookups against a range of MAX(DISTINCT(X),10000) rows. Potentially horribly inefficient.

Comment: @jeffreyweir (1) I present this solution as what I would consider to be the 'simplest' method. Simplest <> most efficient / best. (2) 'equally it might have 1000k rows' = the maximum allowed data set to be held within a single sheet. At that point, Excel itself is hardly the right tool. As always, particular requirements of the user come into play - and in this case, that may mean that my answer is not suitable. But as a general response for others who may not require such a large data set - my answer may be suitable after all.

Comment: @ Grade 'Eh' Bacon Furthermore, your approach requires the user to refresh the PivotTable before checking the result, and only works if the source data is in the file. That's a lot of negatives compared to my approach.

Comment: Excel will quite happily handle data in 1000k rows. Heck, with PowerPivot it won't even break a sweat above that. It is definitely up to the task, and it may well be the only tool the user has at their disposal in any case.  Your approach is very inefficient with *as little as 20k rows*, never mind 100k or a million.  And that's assuming your solution can even be implemented...the source for the PivotTable may not even be in Excel. Your solution requires a refresh. I wouldn't call it the simplest method by a long shot. And it certainly isn't the most efficient.

Comment: @jeffreyweir (1) both our methods check against the pivot table, which mean they both require the pivot table to be refreshed. (2) Excel's natural limit in rows [at least in 2010] is 1040k, so 1 million is basically the highest possible threshold. (3) I specifically stated that my method was not the most efficient, but that it was what I would consider simplest [ie: quickest to implement with easy to understand tools]. (4) I already stated that my method requires access to the source data table. As with all tasks, there are many ways to skin this cat. Up the particular user to consider :-).

Comment: @ Grade 'Eh' Bacon (1) Your  2nd Pivot needs to be refreshed any time the filter changes, so the TRUE/FALSE filter reflects changes. Whereas my calcs are live. (2) My approach will handle a PivotTable with 10k unique items based on source data of 1 Million rows *just as easily* as it will handle source data of 10 thousand: in about 1 second in my high-end PC. Your approach takes 10 seconds to execute *for every 50K rows of source data*. That is miserable by comparison. All those superfluous matches on duplicate items really stack up. Not a good generalized approach, and no simpler than mine.